# Get current/native screen resolution of all monitors in Delphi (DirectX)

Tags: delphi, directx, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors

our delphi application can have multiple DirectX windows, often on multiple screens. up to now the user had to specify the fullscreen resolution using a dropdown with the supported resolutions. it would be very nice, if he could use a setting like 'current' which would be the resolution of the screen on which the window is.

we are using delphi with clootie directX headers. can someone give me a hint, how i would write a method using directX, winAPI or delphi methods to get the resolution of the current screen on which the window is?

kind regards,
thalm

**Final Solution:**

ok, delphi 2007 MultiMon.pas returns crap for GetMonitorInfo, [so i found](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid54D3A0B686F2428E142E99EA9661BBF29A4D516B.aspx?s=md5) this method, which works for me, using the winAPI directly:

```
function GetRectOfMonitorContainingRect(const R: TRect): TRect;
{ Returns bounding rectangle of monitor containing or nearest to R }
type
  HMONITOR = type THandle;
  TMonitorInfo = record
    cbSize: DWORD;
    rcMonitor: TRect;
    rcWork: TRect;
    dwFlags: DWORD;
  end;
const
  MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = $00000002;
var
  Module: HMODULE;
  MonitorFromRect: function(const lprc: TRect; dwFlags: DWORD): HMONITOR; stdcall;
  GetMonitorInfo: function(hMonitor: HMONITOR; var lpmi: TMonitorInfo): BOOL; stdcall;
  M: HMONITOR;
  Info: TMonitorInfo;
begin
  Module := GetModuleHandle(user32);
  MonitorFromRect := GetProcAddress(Module, 'MonitorFromRect');
  GetMonitorInfo := GetProcAddress(Module, 'GetMonitorInfoA');
  if Assigned(MonitorFromRect) and Assigned(GetMonitorInfo) then begin
    M := MonitorFromRect(R, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    Info.cbSize := SizeOf(Info);
    if GetMonitorInfo(M, Info) then begin
      Result := Info.rcMonitor;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := GetRectOfPrimaryMonitor(True);
end;
```

Comment: but i wonder whats the difference between GetMonitorInfo, GetMonitorInfoA and GetMonitorInfoW? can anyone explain that?

Comment: ok, found out, its A for ansi strings and W for wide strings...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var
  MonInfo: TMonitorInfo;
begin
  MonInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(MonInfo);
  GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromWindow(Handle, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST), @MonInfo);
  ShowMessage(Format('Current resolution: %dx%d',
              [MonInfo.rcMonitor.Right - MonInfo.rcMonitor.Left,
               MonInfo.rcMonitor.Bottom - MonInfo.rcMonitor.Top]));
```

Comment: see my post for a complete solution, it only works using the winAPI directly, as delphi 2007 seems to be buggy here.

Comment: Important to notice that this solution is totally independent from the question and works by itself.  Meaning, the GetMonitorInfo used here is the actual GetMonitorInfo from the windows API and not the GetMonitofInfo function implemented in the question.  Just for nobody else to loose a morning on this exercise as I just did.

Answer (score 3):

See the [GetDeviceCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to get the screen resolution.

Use the [TCustomForm.Monitor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TCustomForm.Monitor) property to get the [monitor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Forms.TMonitor) on which the form appears.

Comment: `TCustomForm.Monitor` do what you said, but OP wants to get all of them. Also the `GetDeviceCaps` function is common for getting many attributes and many device types. Anyway I haven't voted here.

Comment: There is `Screen.Monitors` to get all monitors. But as I understand it the OP wants to get the current screen, ie quote: "it would be very nice, if he could use a setting like 'current' which would be the resolution of the screen on which the window is" and thats what Form.Monitor gives?

Answer (score 1):

First use [`EnumDisplayDevices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to obtain a list of all monitor names, see [this](https://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.nativeapi.win32/browse_thread/thread/eaca096b8197b2cd?hl=pt&pli=1) usenet post for how to do that in Delphi. Note that you want the `DeviceName` rather than the `DeviceString`.

Then for each monitor use [`EnumDisplaySettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162611%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)`(lpDisplayDevice.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, lpDevMode)` to obtain the current settings. Here you can also use `NULL` as the device name, which means: "A NULL value specifies the current display device on the computer on which the calling thread is running.". This should usually correspond to the monitor the user is currently on.